# How to create expected datetime in odoo?

Tags: python, datetime, odoo

I tried to create expected datetime for 2 month from plant day. And, this my code :

```
@api.one
@api.depends('date_plant','nursery_plandate')
def calculateplandate(self):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
    if self.date_plant:
        d1 = self.date_plant
        conv = datetime.date(d1)
        d2 = datetime.strptimes(str(conv),fmt)
        d3 = d2.month
        hasil = d3+2
        self.nursery_plandate = hasil
```

and my error :

```
line 148, in calculateplandate
d2 = datetime.date(d1)
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'
```

Comment: if you found your answer than please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this error is, you are passing **string** instead of **date** to **datetime.date()**. When we receive a date data it will be string type, you have to convert that to date type.

Try this code:- I am including a sample code for adding 60 days to your plant date. please make necessary changes to suit your need.

```
def calculateplandate(self):
    if self.date_plant:
        start = datetime.strptime(self.date_plant, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)
        conv = datetime.date(d1)
        hasil = start + datetime.timedelta(days=60) # for adding 60 days
        self.nursery_plandate = hasil
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In odoo 9.0 - fields.Date and fields.Datetime have from_string() and to_string() methods.
You can use these to create the date/datetime objects and then manipulate as required.

```
date = fields.Date.from_string(self.date_plant)
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer, i found another answer for my case , like this :

```
 def calculateplandate(self):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
    if self.date_plant:
        from_date = self.date_plant
        d1=datetime.strptime(str(from_date),fmt)
        date_after_month = datetime.date(d1)+ relativedelta(months=1)
        cetak = date_after_month.strftime(fmt)
        self.nursery_plandate = cetak
```

and i found another question for my case , i cant get value float for months, example i get the value months for 1,5 , i want expected day from planted day is 1,5 month.

Answer (score 0):

**python datetime – Date/time value manipulation.**

**Purpose:** The datetime module includes functions and classes for doing date and time parsing, formatting, and arithmetic.

**Available In**: 2.3 and later

Use the datetime class to hold values consisting of both date and time components. As with date, there are several convenient class methods to make creating datetime instances from other common values.

**Solution:**

```
@api.one
@api.depends('date_plant','nursery_plandate')
def calculateplandate(self):
    if self.date_plant:
        d1 = datetime.strptimes(str(self.date_plant),DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)
        d2 = d1.month + 2
        hasil = datetime.date(d1.year, d2, d1.day)
        self.nursery_plandate = hasil
```

Reference for python datetime:

[datetime — Basic date and time types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

[datetime – Date/time value manipulation](http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/datetime/index.html)

[datetime – Date/time value manipulation](https://pymotw.com/2/datetime/)